# Shortcode into the same shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I'm working on a theme for a framework, and using shortcode to divide the layout, I've found the following problem:

Into a content, I can divide the container into 12 different parts, it also applies for content inside the content (and this is when problem comes), meaning, for sample, if I decide to set 8 and 4 columns, and then the 8 columns I want to divide it into 2 parts, I would need a structure like this:

```
[content]
  [8 columns]
      [content]   <-- PROBLEM IS HERE
          [6 columns]
             half of eight part 1.
          [/6 columns]
          [6 columns]
             half of eight part 2.
          [/6 columns]
      [/content] 
  [/8 columns]

  [4 columns]
     some content here
  [/4 columns]
[/content]
```

When I try to executed this logic, the second content is not being taken, and is displayed as text.. so... I thought the shortcode into a shortcode logic would work, however... it doesn't work if the SC is the same, in short works this (my code) is not working for me.

```
 function content_sc($atts, $content = null){
   return '<div class="content">'.do_shortcode($content).'</div>';
 }
 add_shortcode('content', 'content_sc');
```

Any guessing???

Thanks in advanced!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to [the codex article on shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Nested_Shortcodes), you cannot use a shortcode within itself...which is to say that the following is invalid:

```
[foo]
    [foo]
    [/foo]
[/foo]
```

you should probably make an `inner-content` shortcode or something.

Comment: This is what happens if you try to parse non-regular structures with regular expressions. -.-